# Clarifying Understanding of Presenter Interface

Tags: gwt, mvp

After reading [Large scale application development and MVP](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html), I'm a bit unclear on the `Presenter` interface and I'd appreciate help in clarifying my understanding. Specifically I'm unclear as to whether each Presenter is supposed to have it's own Presenter Interface or is there supposed to be a universal Presenter interface, which all Presenters then implement?

Answer (score 2):

It should be one universal Presenter interface shared by the PresenterImpl classes.

Comment: In practice, I've never needed more than one presenter, so I only make a shared interface for the views - I just pass a concrete presenter around.  Just be ready to extract an interface the minute you _do_ need two presenters.